# Using win32com and/or active_directory, how can I access an email folder by name?

Tags: python, active-directory, outlook, win32com

In python w/ Outlook 2007, using win32com and/or active_directory, how can I get a reference to a sub-folder so that I may move a MailItem to this sub-folder?

I have an inbox structure like:

```
    Inbox
      |
      +-- test
      |
      `-- todo
```

I can access the inbox folder like:

```
import win32com.client
import active_directory
session = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("MAPI.session")
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderInbox)
print '\n'.join(dir(inbox))
```

But when I try to get subdirectory `test` per [Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175261.aspx) the `inbox` object doesn't have the `Folders` interface or any way to get a subdirectory.

How can I get a `Folder` object which points to `test` subdir?

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question but I've been using the win32com package recently and found the documentation troublesome to say the least...My hope is that someone, someday can be saved the turmoil I experienced trying to wrap my head around MSDN's explanation

Here's and example of a python script to traverse through Outlook folders, accessing e-mails where I please.

*Disclaimer*
I shifted around the code and took out some sensitive info so if you're trying to copy and paste it and have it run, good luck.

```
import win32com
import win32com.client
import string
import os
# the findFolder function takes the folder you're looking for as folderName,
# and tries to find it with the MAPIFolder object searchIn

def findFolder(folderName,searchIn):
try:
    lowerAccount = searchIn.Folders
    for x in lowerAccount:
        if x.Name == folderName:
            print 'found it %s'%x.Name
            objective = x
            return objective
    return None
except Exception as error:
    print "Looks like we had an issue accessing the searchIn object"
    print (error)
    return None

def main():

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

ons = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

#this is the initial object you're accessing, IE if you want to access
#the account the Inbox belongs too
one = '<your account name here>@<your domain>.com'

#Retrieves a MAPIFolder object for your account 
#Object functions and properties defined by MSDN at 
#https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder_members(v=office.14).aspx
Folder1 = findFolder(one,ons)

#Now pass you're MAPIFolder object to the same function along with the folder you're searching for
Folder2 = findFolder('Inbox',Folder1)

#Rinse and repeat until you have an object for the folder you're interested in
Folder3 = findFolder(<your inbox subfolder>,Folder2)

#This call returns a list of mailItem objects refering to all of the mailitems(messages) in the specified MAPIFolder
messages = Folder3.Items

#Iterate through the messages contained within our subfolder
for xx in messages:
    try:
        #Treat xx as a singular object, you can print the body, sender, cc's and pretty much every aspect of an e-mail
       #In my case I was writing the body to .txt files to parse...
        print xx.Subject,xx.Sender,xx.Body
       #Using move you can move e-mails around programatically, make sure to pass it a 
        #MAPIFolder object as the destination, use findFolder() to get the object
        xx.Move(Folder3)


    except Exception as err:
        print "Error accessing mailItem"
        print err       


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

PS Hope this doesn't do more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  Yeah.  I found working with this to be painful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something that did work for me was iterating over the folder names. ( When I posted this question, I couldn't figure out the folder names ).

```
import win32com.client
import active_directory
session = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("MAPI.session")
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderInbox)

fldr_iterator = inbox.Folders   
desired_folder = None
while 1:
    f = fldr_iterator.GetNext()
    if not f: break
    if f.Name == 'test':
        print 'found "test" dir'
        desired_folder = f
        break

print desired_folder.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to move a mail item into a "test" subdirectory (simplified by getting rid of gencache stuff):

```
import win32com.client

olFolderInbox = 6
olMailItem = 0

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

item = outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
item.Subject = "test"

test_folder = inbox.Folders("test")
item.Move(test_folder)
```

Comment: This call doesn't work for me `inbox.Folders('test')`.  However I did find that I could iterate over `inbox.Folders` and test against `a_folder.Name`

Comment: Also, you can find all those outlook constants in the win32com  -- `win32com.client.constants.olFolderInbox`

Answer (score 0):

So the below code will grab the "Last" item in the SOURCE folder and then move it to DEST folder.  Sorry the code is a bit blunt I removed all additional features such as reading and saving the mail.

```
import win32com.client

inbox = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")


source = inbox.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["FOLDER_NAME_SOURCE"]
dest = inbox.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["FOLDER_NAME_DEST"]


def moveMail(message):
    print("moving mail to done folder")
    message.Move(dest)
    return print("MOVED")


def getMail():
    message = source.Items.GetLast()
    moveMail(message)


getMail()
```